# Adding reference to ResourceLoader to roslyn compilation

Tags: c#, uwp, roslyn

I'm trying to find all calls to `windows.applicationmodel.resources.resourceloader.getstring` in an UWP application but `compilation.GetSemanticModel().GetSymbolInfo().Symbol` is always `null`. Can someone tell me what `Metadatareference` I have to add so that Roslyn can correctly look up the symbol type?
Here's part of the code I have:

```
    var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
    var project = await workspace.OpenProjectAsync(projectFilepath);
    var compilation = await project.GetCompilationAsync();
    foreach (var tree in compilation.SyntaxTrees) {
        var sm = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree, true);
        var root = await tree.GetRootAsync();
        FindCall(root, sm, calls);
    }
```

`FindCall` looks for `InvocationExpressions` that resemble `resourceLoader.GetString`. But all those calls are missing type information, that is, there's no way of knowing if it's actually a call to `windows.applicationmodel.resources.resourceloader.getstring`.

Answer (score 0):

All MetadataReferences you need should already be loaded by MSBuildWorkspace from the information in your project file.  Check the Workspace.Diagnostics collection to see if there were any errors when opening the project that may cause you not to have correct symbols.

If you are looking for references to specific API's you'll need to find the corresponding Roslyn symbols for those first.  You can do this using the Compilation object you can get from the project. If its a type you are looking for you can get it using the Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName() method. If not, you can use the ISymbol API to find the member you are looking for.